# scala anorm foreach without loading everything into memory

Tags: scala, anorm

the following code prints all rows using scala anorm:

```
import anorm._

val query = s"select col_str, col_num from mytable"

val rowParser: RowParser[~[String, Int]] = SqlParser.str(1) ~ SqlParser.int(2)

def f(row: (String, Int)) {
  println(row._1 + "\t" + row._2)
}

val rows: List[(String, Int)] = SQL(query).as(rowParser.*).map(SqlParser.flatten)

rows.foreach(f)
```

however it needs to load all the data into memory. A solution to avoid loading all data is to use `fold`, as follows:

```
SQL(query).fold(Unit, ColumnAliaser.empty) { (_, r: Row) =>
  println(r[String](1) + "\t" + r[Int](2))
  Unit
}
```

however, here I am not using the `rowParser` and the `flatten`. How can I modify the previous code in order to use the `rowParser` and the `flatten`, without loading everything into memory? something like this (note: this code does not work):

```
SQL(query).as(rowParser.*).map(SqlParser.flatten).fold(Unit, ColumnAliaser.empty) { (_, row: (String, Int)) =>
  f(row)
  Unit
}
```

and, yet more difficult, have to make an implicit `forEach2` function, so that I can run it as follows:

```
SQL(query).as(rowParser.*).map(SqlParser.flatten).forEach2(f)
```

---

**OLD**

some previous code I've tried in that direction:

```
def foreach[T, A, B](sqlQuery: SqlQuery, rowParser: RowParser[~[A, B]], f: (~[A, B]) => T) {
  val result: Either[List[Throwable], Unit.type] = sqlQuery.fold(Unit, ColumnAliaser.empty) { (_, row: Row) =>
    rowParser(row) match {
      case Success(r: ~[A, B]) =>
        f(r)
        Unit
      case Error(err) =>
        throw AnormException(err.toString)
    }
  }

  result.left.foreach { t: Seq[Throwable] =>
    t.foreach(_.printStackTrace)
    t.headOption.foreach { tt => throw tt}
  }
}

def f(row: ~[String, Int]) {
  println(row._1 + "\t" + row._2)
}

foreach(SQL(query), rowParser, f)
```

This works. However, I need to transform `def f(row: (String, Int))` into `def f(row: ~[String, String])`. How can I remove this `~` in my `f` function? Also this `foreach` function expects a row with two columns. how to generalise this to n columns?.

Comment: You can have a look at the documentation about [streaming results](http://cchantep.github.io/anorm/#streaming-results) (Anorm provides an Akka Stream module)

Comment: i already studied this documentation before posting the question.

Comment: As in any Anorm parser `~` is there to represent a tuple-like structure of at least two cols. You cannot "remove" it, but parse it.

Comment: thx for the info.
any idea of how to do something like `SQL(query).as(rowParser.*).map(SqlParser.flatten).foreach(println)`, without loading all the data into memory?

Comment: Rather use `.fold`

Comment: using `.fold` is already proposed in the question. but inside the `fold`, i don't find how to apply the parser (to convert the Row into a tupple or case case class), or how to apply the `SqlParser.flatten` to convert the ~ into a tupple.

Comment: So rather rephrase the question in this way

Comment: I've modified the question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this improvement of your `foreach` good enough? Or do you need something more?

```
object AnormForEachOps {

  import anorm._
  import java.sql.Connection

  implicit class ForEachOps(val query: SqlQuery) extends AnyVal {
    def foreach[T1, T2, R](rowParser: RowParser[~[T1, T2]], f: R => Unit)(implicit connection: Connection, fl: TupleFlattener[(T1 ~ T2) => R]): Unit = {
      query.fold(Unit, ColumnAliaser.empty) { (_, r: Row) =>
        rowParser(r).map(SqlParser.flatten) match {
          case Success(t) =>
            f(t)
            Unit
          case Error(err) =>
            throw AnormException(err.toString)
        }
        Unit
      }
    }
  }

}
```

So your example would become something like this:

```
import AnormForEachOps._
val query = s"select col_str, col_num from mytable"
val rowParser = SqlParser.str(1) ~ SqlParser.int(2)
SQL(query).foreach(rowParser, (r: (String, Int)) => {
    Logger.info(r._1 + "\t" + r._2)
})
```

The main trick in this modification is the implicit `TupleFlattener` argument that does conversion from `~` to usual tuple (via `SqlParser.flatten` call)

Comment: it works! It also works with tuples of 3 elements (instead of 2). great! I modified it also in order to accept Macro.namedParser. And I made foreach return List[Throwable] in case of Error. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidPortabella, it should work for any tuple that  `as(rowParser.*)` works with because it uses the same infrastructure. As for error handling, I copied the one you provided in your example. Obviously it can be changed if you want something else.